# How to send Exceptions to sentry for a django project

Tags: python, django, sentry, raven

Following the [Sentry Django guide](https://docs.sentry.io/clients/python/integrations/django/) I've setup my project and deployed it.

So I configure `RAVEN_CONFIG` with the `SENTRY_DSN` value and `release` values, and include `raven.contrib.django.raven_compat` in my `INSTALLED_APPS`.

I've confirmed that with this configuration the following command will properly generate a message in sentry.

```
python manage.py raven test
```

However, I've created the following django view to raise an exception as an alternative way to confirm that sentry is working, and when I hit this view, I get a 500 response, but nothing shows up in sentry.

*app1/views.py*

```
def error(request):
    x = 1/0  # error for sentry testing
```

> My expectation is that *any* exception (including 500 errors) that
>   occurs in django will be sent to sentry without the need to use
>   logging.

Is my understanding of the raven sentry configuration wrong?
Or, do I need to configure something else?

I am using the LOGGING setting of django, but at the moment I don't care if these messages 'error' or otherwise are sent to sentry.  My main goal at the moment is to catch and send any exception that occurs to sentry.

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'standard': {
            'format': '{asctime} [{levelname:5}] ({name}) {funcName}: {message}',
            'style': '{',
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'standard',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': DJANGO_CORE_LOG_LEVEL,  # Change to DEBUG to see db queries
        },
        'app1': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL,
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'app2': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL,
            'propagate': True,
        }
    },
}
```

**UPDATE**

I've managed to get the `app1.views.error` view to report an error to sentry when using *runserver* locally, but after updating the configuration and deploying it's still not working when deployed. (`manage raven test` does)

Comment: Please post the value of your `LOGGING` setting

Answer (score 4):

From the sentry docs

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': True,
'root': {
    'level': 'WARNING',
    'handlers': ['sentry'],
},
'formatters': {
    'verbose': {
        'format': '%(levelname)s  %(asctime)s  %(module)s '
                  '%(process)d  %(thread)d  %(message)s'
    },
},
'handlers': {
    'sentry': {
        'level': 'ERROR', # To capture more than ERROR, change to WARNING, INFO, etc.
        'class': 'raven.contrib.django.raven_compat.handlers.SentryHandler',
        'tags': {'custom-tag': 'x'},
    },
    'console': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        'formatter': 'verbose'
    }
},
'loggers': {
    'django.db.backends': {
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'propagate': False,
    },
    'raven': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'propagate': False,
    },
    'sentry.errors': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'propagate': False,
    },
},
```

}

Link to doc: https://docs.sentry.io/clients/python/integrations/django/

EDIT: From the comment

```
try:
    do something
except Exception:
    from raven.contrib.django.raven_compat.models import client
    client.captureException()
```

if you don't want to do this manually and want sentry logging to occur anytime an exception block is triggered anywhere in your project, use the logging based solution above.

Comment: I did see this, but the documentation doesn't seem to be clear if this is *required*.  It mentions, `To integrate with the standard library’s logging module, and send all ERROR and above messages to sentry` , but I don't care about logging integration and it doesn't matter if `logging.error()` messages are sent or not.  I only want the exceptions to propagate to sentry.

Comment: The doc doesn't mention if it is required because it is not. You can also propagate this from the place where the exception is being triggered as well. I'm editing the answer to accomodate this.

Comment: Thanks, in previous testing I believe I managed to get the exception to be sent to sentry without manually setting the `client.captureException()`.  It *seems* that it should be possible to set and have ALL exceptions propagate to sentry without having to import and add `client.captureException()` to *every* file in the django project...But since it's not working there's something I don't understand, or is not configured correctly...

Comment: I'm doing something like what is described here: https://scotch.io/tutorials/integrating-sentry-into-django-applications

Comment: Ok, after some testing it *appears* that this additional LOGGING setting is *required* if you have a LOGGING configuration defined.  I'm guessing that without the `'root'` config here the django logger steals the exception so sentry/raven can't reach it...

Answer (score 4):

Just checking in to say that the other answers are totally outdated.

The raven library has been deprecated in favor of sentry-sdk and setting this up does not involve mangling the logging configuration anymore, since a default logging integration will already spy on any logger call.

Just do

```
import sentry_sdk.integrations.django

sentry_sdk.init(
    integrations=[sentry_sdk.integrations.django.DjangoIntegration()],
)
```

in your settings.py and you are good to go (remember to export a `SENTRY_DSN` variable and whatnot).

See https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/python/guides/django/#configure

Answer (score 2):

[Updated Sentry documents](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/python/guides/logging/) mention that with Django integration, you don't need to explicitly define LOGGER in `settings.py`:

```py
import logging

logging.error("Test error event", extra=dict(bar=43))
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Mehran said after configuration of your `LOGGING` in `settings.py`, you will be able to use logging. Let's assume that you have `example` in `loggers` in configuration like;

```
'loggers': {        
    'example': {
        'handlers': ['console', 'sentry'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'propagate': False
    }
}
```

Then;

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger("example")

def test():
    try:
       # some staff
    except Exception as error:
       logger.error("Custom Error Message %s" %error)
```

`logger` also have `warn`, `info` etc.

Comment: yes, I understand this enables you to use the logging module to send messages to sentry, but that's not what I'm looking for.  I want unhandled exceptions to be sent.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to post directly to your Sentry DSN without using any of the Sentry libraries, but using pure `requests`. This can be useful if you're running a version of Python or Django that isn't compatible with Sentry's latest DSN.

I've posted a code for this -including an example test- [here](https://gist.github.com/tzaffi/cb3f1b7f238c345a6be462e922c97ba8)